# Xcode Shell Script Invocation Error Three20

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20, lint

After spending 2 days two refactoring my code (and not being able to compile), I am now getting a Shell Script Invocation Error when building the Three20 library. The file it says is missing is there. What makes no sense is that Three20 has been working fine for months and I did not touch anything in my build settings or anything in Three20. I suspect it has something to do with part of the error that says

```
sourceTree = "<group>'
```

as the combination of " and ' does not look right to me, but no idea how to fix that or why it suddenly happened.

Any ideas ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../scripts/lint", line 341, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "../scripts/lint", line 86, in main
    lint_project(os.environ['PROJECT_FILE_PATH'], options)
File "../scripts/lint", line 156, in lint_project
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(filename)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/Users/jwang/Documents/three20/src/Three20UICommon/Sources/TTGlobalUICommon.m; sourceTree = "<group>'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure it's related to three20. Sounds like you have an issue with the Xcode project itself

Try opening `project.pbxproj` and search for `sourceTree = "<group>'`

somehow you got a syntax error in that file, which has to be fixed.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling Three20 (which in and of itself is impossible) and that resolved the error. I then reinstalled a clean version of Three20. So not sure how the install got corrupted, or how to fix the issue, but the work around worked. But thanks anyway.